# Erro ao Criar Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migrations

Estou criando um cadastro de usuário em C#, porém ao incluir a camada domain e vou criar o migration está acontecendo o erro abaixo. não consegui identificar o que ocorre.

"No suitable constructor found for entity type 'User'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'cellPhone', 'address'."

```
namespace AgendaWeb.Domain.Users
{
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string Cpf { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Phone { get; private set; }
    public string Cellphone { get; private set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
    public string ProfileType { get; private set; }

    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    public User(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address )
    {
        ValidateValues(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);
        SetProperties(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);

    }

    public void Update(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        ValidateValues(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);
        SetProperties(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);

    }

    private void SetProperties(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        FullName = fullName;
        Cpf = cpf;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        Cellphone = cellPhone;
        PhotoUrl = photoUrl;
        Password = password;
        RegistrationDate = registrationDate;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        ProfileType = profileType;
        Address = address;
    }

    private static void ValidateValues(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        DomainException.When(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName), "O campo nome é obrigatório!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: como Gustavo já respondeu, você precisa ter um construtor sem parâmetros para que o EF crie uma instância, você pode simplesmente adicionar `public User(){}` à sua classe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Entity Framework no .NET Full, é necessário ter um construtor sem parâmetros protected.

Caso você esteja usando o Entity Framework Core, é possível ter construtores com parâmetros, mas não é possível usar os tipos complexos como parâmetros, sendo assim, só tipos primitivos podem ser utilizados no construtor.

No EF Core, você tem duas saídas: criar um construtor protegido sem parâmetros, tirar os tipos complexos do construtor existente.

Fonte: [Tipos de entidade com construtores - EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/constructors)